# How to check whether a string is a concatenation of other strings with a character inserted between each string in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to check whether a user-inputted string is contained in a list of other strings AND any permutation of those strings, separated by a "*".

In other words, here's the code I have so far:

```
user_string=raw_input("Please supply a string")


viable_entries=['this', 'that', 'something else']

if user_string in viable_entries:
    print "here I'd move on with my script"
```

I'd also want to print "here I'd move on with my script" if user_string = "something else*this" or "this*that", etc.

Is there an easy, pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split the input and use `set.issubset`:

```
if set(user_string.split('*')).issubset(viable_entries):
     ...
```

Note that this gives `True` even if an entry is repeated (`"this*this"`).  If you want to prevent the user providing repeated entries you can use `len(set)`:

```
entries = user_string.split('*')
if set(entries).issubset(viable_entries) and len(set(entries)) == len(entries):
     ...
```

Answer (score 1):

ecatmur's solution is better, but the 'brute force' approach is to generate a power set of viable_entries and check based on that. Adapted from the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) page:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (2,1) (3,1) (3,2) (1,2,3)..."
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(permutations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

After that, `"*".join(X) for X in powerset(viable_entries)` would give you your list to match against.

Comment: I really like the powerset approach as well, but I've never used chain.from_iterable before and keep getting this error: "NameError: global name 'chain' is not defined". I tried "import itertools" and still no dice. Any advice?

Comment: @Atticus29: If you only import itertools, you have to qualify the various names, so use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and `itertools.permutations`